# Luigi child dependency in subclass

Tags: dependencies, task, luigi

I have a flow A->B->C where C depend on B, B depend on A
Let say I have another flow D->B->C

I try to reuse the task. How can I easily reuse?

I can create a subclass that inherit Task B and change the requires to Task D, however to allow D->B->C, I need again to create subclass that inherit Task C and change the requires method to subclass of B.

This is very troublesome and I wonder is there a easy way to do this> Or this is the correct behavior of luigi?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make sense, possibly by being too abstract. How does B or C know whether it requires() Task A or Task D? Do A and D produce the same type of output? If there are different situations, you should code those in a way changes the requirements of the tasks. Here's a partial, oversimplified example, based on the very limited info you have provided.

```py
class TaskC(luigi.Task):
    tasktype = luigi.Parameter() 
    def requires():
        return TaskB(tasktype=self.tasktype)

class TaskB(luigi.Task):
    tasktype = luigi.Parameter()
    def requires():
       if self.tasktype == "A":
          return TaskA()
       else:
          return TaskD()
    def run():
       file = self.input().open('r')
       #do something with output from either
```